# Установка Ubuntu на виртуальную машину

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

Хочу установить Ubuntu 18 на виртуальную машину, скачал virtualBox 6.0.12, установил, потом скачал образ Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (Bionic Beaver). Создал виртуальную машину, выбрал образ, выделил 4гб озу, видеопамять 128мб, но при запуске виртуальной машины появляется фиолетовый экран и дальше ничего не грузит https://prnt.sc/p9j03c. Подскажите, в чем может быть ошибка, буду благодарен любой помощи

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Вы долго ждали? Возможно процессор вашей хостовой машины не достаточно силен, и просто происходит долго загрузка Ubuntu...

Comment: @nikialeksey когда запустил первый раз ждал около 5 минут, при следующем запуске ждал 20 минут но так ничего и не произошло

Comment: прикрепите, тогда, пожалуйста, скрины настроек виртуалки Общие -> Основные, и Система -> Процессор

Comment: Решено. Отключил отключил Hyper-V и это помогло, только теперь докер не запускается, т.к. для него нужно чтобы Hyper-V был включен, приходится то врубать то отрубать его заново, но это уже совсем другая история